# Backup and Restore SharePoint Online Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

How we can take backup of SharePoint Online sites and restore it?

Answer (score 0):

There are not powershell commands to take backup and restore SharePoint online site.

Microsoft supports and takes backup of your site of last 14 days. You can contact microsoft and have them restore the site to a time up to and including 2 weeks from the time of the restore.

You can refer to below articles for reference.

https://threewill.com/the-4-options-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-online-backup-and-restore/
https://synkventures.com/2017/01/11/backup-and-restore-strategy-for-sharepoint-onlinesharepoint-office365/

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, Microsoft take care of the backup of SPO contents. You just need to contact MS to have a restore of you SPO sites. 
Here is an article could give you some more information:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SharePoint-Online-Backup-Strategies-for-a-Cloudy-Day/m-p/225418

Answer (score 0):

There are third party tools out there that allow you to backup / restore sharepoint online down to the file level.  Veeam for example.